# Prove the Hyperboloid $S =\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} | x^2 +y^2-z^2 =1\}$ can be covered by a single surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

> The hyperboloid of one sheet is
> $$ S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}.$$
>
> Show that, for every $\theta$, the straight line
>
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{align*} 
> (x-z)\cos \theta &= (1-y)\sin \theta \\ 
> (x+z)\sin \theta &= (1+y)\cos \theta 
> \end{align*}
> \right.
> $$
>
> is contained in $S$, and that every point of the hyperboloid lies on one of these lines. deduce that $S$ can be covered by a single surface patch, and hence is a surface.

Im struggling a bit with the intuition behind this question.

To get a surface patch covering $S$, we define $\boldsymbol{\sigma}: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$
\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\theta,v) = 
(\sin 2\theta, -\cos 2\theta, 0) + t \, (\cos 2\theta, \sin 2\theta, 1) 
\quad \text{for } 0 \leq \theta < \pi.
$$
Now supposedly this patch covers the whole surface.

Where I'm stuck is the fact that the interval $ 0 \le \theta < \pi$ is not an open set and the definition of a surface patch $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is a homeomorphism  $\boldsymbol{\sigma}:U \to  S \cap W$ where $U$ is a open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So in our case
$U = \{ (\theta,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq \theta < \pi \}$
is not open but if we were to restrict it to
$U = \{ (\theta,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 < \theta< \pi \}$
whilst this is open the surface patch $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is no longer a single surface patch covering the whole of $S$. But apparently this hyperboloid  **is** covered by a single surface patch . So where is my intuition going wrong?
How comes in the case of this hyperboloid we do not have the same issue as we have with a circular cylinder (which requires two patches)?

Comment: You are totally correct.

Comment: Your proposed surface patch maps $(\theta, t)$ to the surface, where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ is interpreted as a polar angle coordinate. You need to rework the formulas to map a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is already rotationally symmetric to the surface. By necessity, this open region will need to be diffeomorphic to a cylinder/hyperboloid.

Comment: @SammyBlack Sorry I don't quite follow could you expand?

Comment: I conjecture that "covered" in the question might refer to a covering space. If you let not only $v$ (sometimes called $t$) but also $\theta$ range over all of $\mathbb R$, your map from all of $\mathbb R^2$ onto the hyperboloid is an infinite-sheeted covering space.